# Android калькулятор не работает

Tags: java, android

Написал я простенький калькулятор с вычислением процентов. Некоторые числа он обрабатывает нормально и все выводит туда куда нужно. Но иногда он просто выводит заголовок но не выводит число. Ниже предоставлен код на джаве.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
public void Resultat_Click(View v){

        EditText num_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num_text);
        EditText percent_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percent_text);
        TextView res1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res1);
        TextView res2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res2);

        float b;
        int a;

        a=0;
        b=0;

        String str = percent_text.getText().toString();
        a=Integer.parseInt(str);

        str = num_text.getText().toString();
        b=Float.parseFloat(str);

        res1.setText("УО: "+Double.toString((a*b/100)));
        res2.setText("КСО: " + Double.toString(b - ((a * b) / 100 )));

        a=0;
        b=0;

    }
```

Comment: Иногда - когда?

Comment: Закономерности нету, просто одни числа считает другие нет. Вразброс.

Comment: На мой недалекий взгляд, нужны примеры, когда не работает, а так "поди туда, не знаю куда..."

Comment: Непонятно, что вы там делаете. Сделайте воспроизводимый пример, с проблемой, а то непонятно, что у вас иногда не выводит и куда не выводит. Описывайте вопрос более развернуто и подробно, вы и себе будете помогать, тем, что помогаете нам, быстрее понять, чтобы дать ответ вам.

Answer (score 0):

Обработка чисел с плавающей точкой может не работать если указан неверный разделитель. Для Америки это точка, для Европы — запятая.